# How do I initialize the base (super) class?

Tags: python, oop

In Python, consider I have the following code:

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        
class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        # how do I initialize the SuperClass __init__ here?
```

How do I initialize the `SuperClass __init__` in the subclass? I am following the Python tutorial and it doesn't cover that. When I searched on Google, I found more than one way of doing. What is the standard way of handling this?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Python (until version 3) supports "old-style" and new-style classes. New-style classes are derived from `object` and are what you are using, and invoke their base class through [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), e.g.

```
class X(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    pass

  def doit(self, bar):
    pass

class Y(X):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Y, self).__init__(123)

  def doit(self, foo):
    return super(Y, self).doit(foo)
```

Because python knows about old- and new-style classes, there are different ways to invoke a base method, which is why you've found multiple ways of doing so.

For completeness sake, old-style classes call base methods explicitly using the base class, i.e.

```
def doit(self, foo):
  return X.doit(self, foo)
```

But since you shouldn't be using old-style anymore, I wouldn't care about this too much.

Python 3 only knows about new-style classes (no matter if you derive from `object` or not).

Comment: As of Python 3.5.2, you can omit the arguments to `super()`, see Bob Jordan's answer below.

Answer (score 57):

As of python 3.5.2, you can use:

```
class C(B):
def method(self, arg):
    super().method(arg)    # This does the same thing as:
                           # super(C, self).method(arg)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: I'm confused by your example (which I see is taken straight from the python docs). In this particular case, `method` just calls the function of the same name of the parent class -- wouldn't the effect be identical, if this `def`inition had been omitted, i.e. `method` inherited from `B`?

Answer (score 46):

Both

```
SuperClass.__init__(self, x)
```

or

```
super(SubClass,self).__init__( x )
```

will work (I prefer the 2nd one, as it adheres more to the DRY principle).

See here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Comment: wrong. super only works with new-style classes, and is the only proper way to call a base when using new-style classes. Furthermore, you also need to pass 'self' explicitly using the old-style construct.

Comment: @Ivo - the OP gave a new-style class in the example, and there's little point in talking about the difference between new-style and old-style as no one should use old-style any more. The link I gave (to the Python docs) suggest that there's more than one "proper" way to call the super-class `__init__`.

Answer (score 31):

> ### How do I initialize the base (super) class?
>
> ```
> class SuperClass(object):
>     def __init__(self, x):
>         self.x = x
>
> class SubClass(SuperClass):
>     def __init__(self, y):
>         self.y = y
> ```

Use a `super` object to ensure you get the next method (as a bound method) in the method resolution order. In Python 2, you need to pass the class name and `self` to super to lookup the bound `__init__` method:

```
 class SubClass(SuperClass):
      def __init__(self, y):
          super(SubClass, self).__init__('x')
          self.y = y
```

In Python 3, there's a little magic that makes the arguments to `super` unnecessary - and as a side benefit it works a little faster:

```
 class SubClass(SuperClass):
      def __init__(self, y):
          super().__init__('x')
          self.y = y
```

Hardcoding the parent like this below prevents you from using cooperative multiple inheritance:

```
 class SubClass(SuperClass):
      def __init__(self, y):
          SuperClass.__init__(self, 'x') # don't do this
          self.y = y
```

Note that [`__init__` may only return `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) - it is intended to modify the object in-place.

### Something `__new__`

There's another way to initialize instances - and it's the only way for subclasses of immutable types in Python. So it's required if you want to subclass `str` or `tuple` or another immutable object.

You might think it's a classmethod because it gets an implicit class argument. But it's [actually a staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). So you need to call `__new__` with `cls` explicitly.

We usually return the instance from `__new__`, so if you do, you also need to call your base's `__new__` via `super` as well in your base class. So if you use both methods:

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        return super(SuperClass, cls).__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class SubClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, y):
        return super(SubClass, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        super(SubClass, self).__init__('x')
```

Python 3 sidesteps a little of the weirdness of the super calls caused by `__new__` being a static method, but you still need to pass `cls` to the non-bound `__new__` method:

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class SubClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, y):
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        super().__init__('x')
```

Comment: In your hardcoding example: Why do you say `SuperClass.__init__(self, 'x') # don't do this`?

Comment: Because that's the wrong way to do it.