# How to bring a nested class to inherit?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, nested

I'm trying to initialize an inheriting class inside another class, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to solve.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694371/how-do-i-initialize-the-base-super-class-in-python) that inheriting generally works following way:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        print text

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Bar, self).__init__(text)
```

This works, however, if I put the `Bar`-class into another class, the code doesn't work anymore.

```
class Whatever(object):
    class Bar(Foo):
        def __init__(self, text):
            super(Bar, self).__init__(text)

    def __init__(self, text):
        test = self.Bar(text)
```

Python gets confused with the namespace:

```
super(Bar, self).__init__(text)
NameError: global name 'Bar' is not defined
```

What to do? Thanks!

Comment: Try referring to `Bar` as `Whatever.Bar`.

Comment: Tried. Works. Thank you! :)

Comment: This hasn't anything to do with class inheritance. If `Bar` inherited from `object`, you'd *still* get the same error. If `Bar` didn't inherit from anything, the same error would occur. That's because `Bar` is not a global when you make it an attribute of another class instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, I didn't think properly, a class witch is in its own nametable wouldn't make sense at all.
@LennartRegebro Because the obvious reason: Every `Whatever` needs a `Foo`, but not always the exact same...

Comment: @user3424423: I actually missed the `super()` line; I was referring to the `test = Bar(text)` line.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

You have to refer to `Bar` with `Whatever.Bar`, so it looks like this:

```
class Whatever(object):
    class Bar(Foo):
        def __init__(self, text):
            super(Whatever.Bar, self).__init__(text)

    def __init__(self, text):
        test = self.Bar(text)
```

Comment: And you could also use `self.Bar` instead of `Whatever.Bar`.

Comment: No, you can't. (Don't ask me why) This produces the error `'Bar' has no attribute 'Bar'`

Comment: Actually I know why. If you write `self.bar`, python searches for the `Bar` in the local namespace of `Bar`. If you write `Bar` only, it searches in the namespace of the `__init__()`-Method, and if it doesn't find anything, it looks in the global-Namespace. You have to write `Whatever.Bar`, because `Whatever.Bar` is in the global-Namespace, `Bar` is not.

Comment: @user3424423: there are *two* locations you need to adjust your `Bar` reference. The `Whatever.__init__` method also needs to qualify `Bar` (it is currently looking for a global). It is *there* you can use `self.Bar` as well as `Whatever.Bar`.