# Explicit passing of Self when calling super class's __init__ in python

Tags: python, subclass, superclass, super, self

This question is in relation to posts at [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python) , [How do I initialize the base (super) class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694371/how-do-i-initialize-the-base-super-class-in-python) , and [Python: How do I make a subclass from a superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607612/python-how-do-i-make-a-subclass-from-a-superclass) which describes two ways to initialize a `SuperClass` from within a `SubClass` as

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        return
    def superMethod(self):
        return


## One version of Initiation
class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        SuperClass.__init__(self)
    def subMethod(self):
        return
```

or

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        return
    def superMethod(self):
        return

## Another version of Initiation
class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__()
    def subMethod(self):
        return
```

So I'm a little confused about needing to **explicitly** pass `self` as a parameter in 
`SuperClass.__init__(self)` 
and 
`super(SubClass, self).__init__()`. 
(In fact if I call `SuperClass.__init__()` I get the error

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

). But when calling constructors or any other class method (ie :

```
## Calling class constructor / initiation
c = SuperClass()
k = SubClass()

## Calling class methods
c.superMethod()
k.superMethod()
k.subMethod()
```

), The `self` parameter is passed **implicitly** .

My understanding of the `self` keyword is it is not unlike the `this` pointer in C++, whereas it provides a reference to the class instance. Is this correct?

If there would always be a current instance (in this case `SubClass`), then why does `self` need to be explicitly included in the call to `SuperClass.__init__(self)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is simply method binding, and has very little to do with `super`. When you can `x.method(*args)`, Python checks the type of `x` for a method named `method`. If it finds one, it "binds" the function to `x`, so that when you call it, `x` will be passed as the first parameter, before the rest of the arguments.

When you call a (normal) method via its class, no such binding occurs. If the method expects its first argument to be an instance (e.g. `self`), you need to pass it in yourself.

The actual implementation of this binding behavior is pretty neat. Python objects are "descriptors" if they have a `__get__` method (and/or `__set__` or `__delete__` methods, but those don't matter for methods). When you look up an attribute like `a.b`, Python checks the class of `a` to see if it has a attribute `b` that is a descriptor. If it does, it translates `a.b` into `type(a).b.__get__(a, type(a))`. If `b` is a function, it will have a `__get__` method that implements the binding behavior I described above. Other kinds of descriptors can have different behaviors. For instance, the `classmethod` decorator replaces a method with a special descriptor that binds the function the class, rather than the instance.

Python's `super` creates special objects that handle attribute lookups differently than normal objects, but the details don't matter too much for this issue. The binding behavior of methods called through `super` is just like what I described in the first paragraph, so `self` gets passed automatically to the bound method when it is called. The only thing special about `super` is that it may bind a different function than you'd get lookup up the same method name on `self` (that's the whole point of using it).

Answer (score 5):

The following example might elucidate things:

```
class Example:
    def method(self):
        pass

>>> print(Example.method)
<unbound method Example.method>

>>> print(Example().method)
<bound method Example.method of <__main__.Example instance at 0x01EDCDF0>>
```

When a method is bound, the instance is passed implicitly. When a method is unbound, the instance needs to be passed explicitly.

The other answers will definitely offer some more detail on the binding process, but I think it's worth showing the above snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is non-trivial and would probably warrant a good article. A very good explanation of how `super()` works is brilliantly given by Raymond Hettinger in a Pycon 2015 talk, available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) and a related [article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).
I will attempt a short answer and if it is not sufficient I (and hopefully the community) will expand on it.
The answer has two key pieces:

- Python's `super()` needs to have an object on which the method being overridden is called, so it is explicitly passed with self. This is not the only possible implementation and in fact, in Python 3, it is no longer required that you pass the self instance.
- Python `super()` is not like Java, or other compiled languages, `super`. Python's implementation is designed to support the *multiple collaborative inheritance* paradigm, as explained in Hettinger's talk. 
  This has an interesting consequence in Python: the method resolution in `super()` depends not only on the parent class, but on the children classes as well (consequence of multiple inheritance). Note that Hettinger is using Python 3.

The official Python 2.7 [documentation on `super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) is also a good source of information (better understood after watching the talk, in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Because in `SuperClass.__init__(self)`, you're calling the method on the class, not the instance, so it cannot be passed implicitly. Similarly you cannot just call `SubClass.subMethod()`, but you *can* call `SubClass.subMethod(k)` and it'll be equivalent to `k.subMethod()`. Similarly if `self` refers to a `SubClass` then `self.__init__()` means `SubClass.__init__(self)`, so if you want to call `SuperClass.__init` you have to call it directly.