# Object not accessible inside a function in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I am facing an issue.

Below is my code:

```
class LocalQueryDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self = dict()

    def addvalue(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

#Global definition of the object, "local_query_dict"

local_query_dict = LocalQueryDictionary()

def save_local_query(query_name_input, query_val_input):

    local_query_dict.addvalue(str(query_name_input.get()), str(query_val_input.get()))
    localQuery_listbox.insert(END, str(query_name_input.get()))
```

I am getting "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'addvalue'".

Please help me on the same.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: remove the __init__ function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, please share a [mcve]. `__init__` function makes no sense, but it's not what's causing that error.

Comment: Are you trying to initialize base class over here `self = dict()` ? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46940954/8601641), or else remove `__init__` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are subclassing dict for a reason, just initialize it.

And for adding values you can try `__setitem__`

```
class LocalQueryDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def addvalue(self, key, value):
        self.__setitem__(key, value)
```

Then

```
a = LocalQueryDictionary()
a.addvalue('product', 'Lorem')
a.addvalue('state', 'NY')
print(a)
#=> {'product': 'Lorem', 'state': 'NY'}
```

Comment: The original class `LocalQueryDictionary` works as well...

Comment: interesting. i just expected it will not work and even didn't check. now i have a question, how? :)

Answer (score 0):

The conventional name 'self' is a reference to the class.

If I understand your intention correctly, then what you probably want is this:-

```
class LocalQueryDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def addvalue(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value


lqd = LocalQueryDictionary()
lqd.addvalue('k', 'v')
print(lqd)
```